# If $T: V \to V$ is a linear map, are there cases for which $V \neq KerT \oplus ImT$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Pretty basic question I guess, but when is it true to say that given  $T: V \to V$ a linear map, then $V =KerT \oplus ImT$ ? Are there cases where it's not true?

Comment: What are the kernel and image of $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Just in case it's hiding a misconception, $V$ is merely guaranteed to be *isomorphic* to $\ker(T) \oplus \mathrm{im}(T)$. There isn't even a guarantee that this is an internal direct sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rank-nullity theorem tells us that in finite-dimensional spaces, $\dim \ker T + \dim \operatorname{im} T = \dim V$.  As a consequence, the following statements are equivalent (when $V$ is finite dimensional):

- $V = \ker (T) \oplus \operatorname{im}(T)$
- $\ker(T) \cap \operatorname{im}(T) = \{0\}$
- $\dim \operatorname{im}(T^2) = \dim \operatorname{im}(T)$
- $\dim \operatorname{im}(T^k) = \dim \operatorname{im}(T)$ for all $k \geq 1$
- $\dim \ker(T^2) = \dim \ker(T)$
- $\dim \ker(T^k) = \dim \ker(T)$ for all $k \geq 1$

Notably, any self-adjoint transformation on an inner product space *does* satisfy $V = \ker (T) \oplus \operatorname{im}(T)$.  An example of a transformation that *doesn't* satisfy this condition is
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$

Comment: Also equivalent to $V = \ker(T) + \mathrm{im}(T)$.